# unable to loacte credentials while make a connection with DB using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I want to make connection to my Database and want to retrieve data. I am currently using AWS amazon linux2  instance. I used boto3 to connect.

```
def db_conn():
    secret_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    try:
        client = boto3.client('secretsmanager',region_name="ap-southeast-2")
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_id)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    else:
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            Secret_Json = json.loads(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])
    if Secret_Json is None:
        print("secret string is null")
        exit()
    driver = 'postgresql+psycopg2://'
    db_user = Secret_Json['username']
    db_pw = Secret_Json['password']
    db_address_port_db = Secret_Json['host'] + \
                         ':' + \
                         str(Secret_Json['port']) + \
                         '/' + \
                         Secret_Json['dbInstanceIdentifier']
    application.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    application.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = driver + db_user + ':' + db_pw + '@' + db_address_port_db
    db = SQLAlchemy(application)
    return db
```

I face an error saying no credentials found

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 622, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 641, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 132, in _send_request
    request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 116, in create_request
    operation_name=operation_model.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 90, in handler
    return self.sign(operation_name, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 160, in sign
    auth.add_auth(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 357, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

Please help me what to do to solve this?

Comment: How are you expecting to connect to the AWS IAM role, IAM user?

Comment: You would typically **assign an IAM Role to the Amazon EC2 instance**. boto3 will automatically use the IAM Role to obtain credentials via EC2 Instance Metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign an **IAM role** to your instance with required permissions:

- [How do I assign an existing IAM role to an EC2 instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/assign-iam-role-ec2-instance/)
- [IAM roles for Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)

Boto3 will use the permissions from the role to get access to your resources, such as **Secrets Manager**.

The role could include, for example, an inline policy to read from `Secrets Manager`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "Resource": "<arn-of-your-sercert>"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you use KMS for encrypting your secret, KMS permissions may also be required.